# Android Dont update score if button has been click

Tags: android, android-fragments, if-statement

Im making a quiz app. If the user has entered the correct answer, they get +1 in their score.
However, I want to make such that if a Hint button has been clicked, then they don't get their score updated.

My code is looking as the following right now

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

    private EditText userAnswer;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_two, null);
        userAnswer = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.showCorrect);
        final TextView hintv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textHint);
        //final int a;

        final Button submit = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.submitBtn1);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String theAnswer = (userAnswer.getText().toString());
                if (theAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("Greece")) {
                    if (hintv.isEnabled()) {                         //Doesn't work
                        ((Play) getActivity()).updateScore(1);
                    }
                    tv.setText("Correct!");
                } else {
                    tv.setText("Wrong");
                }
                submit.setEnabled(false);

            }
        });

        final Button skip = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.skipBtn);
        skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                submit.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });

        final Button hint = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.hintBtn);
        hint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                hintv.setText("The capital is Athens \n The country is in Europe \n It starts with G... ");
                hint.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
```

What if statement should I write instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `boolean` flag, for example:

```
private boolean hintUsed;
```

When the hint button has been clicked, set this to true:

```
hint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        hintv.setText("The capital is Athens \n The country is in Europe \n It starts with G... ");
        hint.setEnabled(false);
        hintUsed = true;
    }
});
```

And then when checking the answer, only award the point if `hintUsed` is still false:

```
if (!hintUsed) { 
    ((Play) getActivity()).updateScore(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a boolean var that change to true after hint button was clicked.

```
  private EditText userAnswer;
    private boolean isHintButtonClicked = false;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_two, null);
    userAnswer = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.showCorrect);
    final TextView hintv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textHint);
    //final int a;

    final Button submit = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.submitBtn1);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String theAnswer = (userAnswer.getText().toString());
            if (theAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("Greece")) {
                if (!isHintButtonClicked) {                        
                    ((Play) getActivity()).updateScore(1);
                }
                tv.setText("Correct!");
            } else {
                tv.setText("Wrong");
            }
            isHintButtonClicked = false;
            submit.setEnabled(false);

        }
    });

    final Button skip = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.skipBtn);
    skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            submit.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    final Button hint = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.hintBtn);
    hint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            isHintButtonClicked = true;
            hintv.setText("The capital is Athens \n The country is in Europe \n It starts with G... ");
            hint.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```

And of course dont forget to add

```
isHintButtonClicked = false;
```

So it would be false again for the next question.